# Посчитать количество файлов в папке

Tags: php

Собственно вопрос: необходимо на PHP посчитать количество файлов в папке.
Поправка: считать только файлы, без учёта вложенных папок.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Например так:

```
$dir = opendir('path/to/dir');
$count = 0;
while($file = readdir($dir)){
    if($file == '.' || $file == '..' || is_dir('path/to/dir' . $file)){
        continue;
    }
    $count++;
}
echo 'Количество файлов: ' . $count;
```

Comment: $file - это имя_файла.расширение, поэтому можно фильтровать по нужному типу.

Comment: разве так он считает только файлы, а не файлы и папки?

Comment: Сорри, добавл проверку на папку

Comment: '.' и '..' это тоже папки, т.е. проверка лишняя. Тут другой вопрос - правильно ли считать линки, сокеты и т.п. как файлы. 

На sh в \*nix я бы написал 

    if [ -f $file ] ; then 
       cnt=`expr $cnt + 1`
    fi

Answer (score 6):

Я думаю можно еще проще сделать.

```
echo count(scandir('/folder/'));
```

Comment: "scandir — Получить список файлов и каталогов" - с php.net.
Только файлы выбрать нельзя

Comment: Пропустите массив через дополнительный фильтр, вот и вся проблема.

Comment: Если в папке будет много файлов и папок, то вариант со `scandir` слишком ресурсоёмкий в отличии от `opendir`

Answer (score 2):

Взято отсюда
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801370/count-how-many-files-in-directory-php

```
$fi = new FilesystemIterator("/path/to/folder", FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
printf("Всего файлов: %d", iterator_count($fi));
```

Comment: Учитывая, что вопросу уже восьмой год пошел, со скоростью реакции у вас не очень.

Comment: У меня сейчас стоит более широкая задача: посчитать количество файлов, их размеры, дату самого старого и самого нового, поэтому сам применил итерацию по результатам 

`glob(rtrim($path, '/') . '/*', GLOB_NOSORT)`

Comment: Ниже @ustatos привел интересную статистику, которая показывает, что именно для подсчёта файлов FilesystemIterator даёт самый быстрый результат.
Сейчас зашёл в консоль, субъективно 'ls' выполнилось мгновенно, 'ls -l' 0.5-1 c на паре десятков файлов. Видимо, получение аттрибутов файлов - это достаточно долгая операция

Answer (score 1):

```
$cfiles = count(array_diff(scandir("/path/to/folder"), [".", ".."]));
printf("Всего файлов: %d", $cfiles);
```

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста небольшие пояснения к коду.

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант с итератором и немного статистики

```
While:             0.42448782920837  
FilesystemIterator 0.0074279308319092  
DirectoryIterator: 0.77696204185486 


echo countFile(__DIR__);

function countFile($dir)
{
    $iterator = new DirectoryIterator($dir);
    $count = 0;
    iterator_apply(
        $iterator,
        'isFile',
        [$iterator, &$count]
    );
    return $count;
}

function isFile(Iterator $item, int &$count) 
{
    if ($item->isFile()) {
        $count++;
    }
    return true;
}
```